# Column filtering and stacking on table not working on backspace in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created my table with jQuery and have it using filtering on the column. However, ran into something interesting.

Below is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4sy5dweg/1/

So my issue is as follows -

Once I find what I am looking for by filtering. If I decided to start backspacing I want it to continue searching that column and obviously start going backwards on searching.

I hope that makes sense.

```
 $.extend($.expr[":"], {
            "containsIN": function (elem, i, match, array) {
                return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }
        });
        $("[id*=TXTSEARCH]").keyup(function () {
            tablename = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            mytd = $(this).closest('th');
            var indexColumn = mytd.index();
            var data = this.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            var jo = $("[id*=" + tablename + "]").find("tr:not(:first)");
            jo.filter(function (i, v) {
                var $t = $(this).children(":eq(" + indexColumn + ")");
                for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                    if ($t.is(":not(:containsIN('" + data[d] + "'))")) {
                        console.log(data[d]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }).hide();
        })
```

I know the issue has to do with hiding that row on initial search. However, somehow for isntance if someone has a typo and goes to backspace it wont show anything because that row is still hidden. Is there a way to keep the other filters in place and basically remove the filter from the row being corrected?

I hope I am making sense.

Update I have attempted the following -

```
 $("[id*=TXTSEARCH]").keyup(function () {
            var tablename = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            console.log(tablename);
            var FindMyRow;
            $("#" + tablename).find('th:visible').find($("[id*=TXTSEARCH]")).each(function () {
                FindMyRow = $(this).closest('th:visible');
                var indexColumn = FindMyRow.index();
                console.log($(this).attr('id') + " " + indexColumn);
                var data = this.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
                var jo = $("[id*=" + tablename + "]").find("tr:not(:first)");
                jo.show().filter(function (i, v) {
                    var $t = $(this).children(":eq(" + indexColumn + ")");
                    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                        if ($t.is(":not(:containsIN('" + data[d] + "'))")) {
                            console.log(data[d]);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }).hide();
            });
```

to no avail.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't jam tags on the front, and don't YELL. :) See [ask].

Comment: I see a `.hide()` but no corresponding `.show()`.   Could *probably* just change `jo.filter(...` to `jo.show().filter(...`.  Depends on number of rows and how long the filter takes whether that would be jarring (or how jquery works, would need to test, think it only updates when your code has finished)

Comment: I did attempt with `jo.show().filter(fun` however it then only allows filtering on one column. If you see in the fiddle I have it basically combining. I am thinking it somehow has to clear that specific column "results" . Just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to change my way of doing it.

I added a button to each column header that the user can click on so that if they make a type they just check it before clicking it.

```
 $("[id*=BTNSEARCH]").click(function (e) {
       
        e.preventDefault();
        var tablename = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        mytd = $(this).closest('th');
        var TextBoxToSearch = ($(this).prev('input').val());
        var indexColumn = mytd.index();
        FindMyRow = $(this).closest('th:visible');
        var indexColumn = FindMyRow.index();
        var data = TextBoxToSearch.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var jo = $("#" + tablename).find("tr:not(:first)");
        jo.filter(function (i, v) {
            var $t = $(this).children(":eq(" + indexColumn + ")");
            for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                if ($t.is(":not(:containsIN('" + data[d] + "'))")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }).hide();
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).